# Run the interactive F# in 32 bit mode on Mac

Tags: macos, winforms, f#, f#-interactive

When I'm inside `fsharpi` on Mac Os and I do

```
open System.Windows.Forms;;
let f = new Form();;
```

I get the following warning

> **WARNING: The Carbon driver has not been ported to 64bits, and very few parts of Windows.Forms will work properly, or at all**
>
> Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
>
> Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
>
> Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
>
> Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
>
> val f : Form = System.Windows.Forms.Form

And in fact nothing works.
Is there a way of using the 32bits Carbon driver? Or another way of running an F# app that uses windows forms on Mac?

Comment: I sadly have to use windows forms and fsharp (it's for a university course and cannot switch to another language and/or another gui library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem last week running some Windows Forms code in FSI from VS Code on macOS. Setting environment variable `MONO_ENV_OPTIONS=--arch=32` should do the trick:

```
$ MONO_ENV_OPTIONS=--arch=32 fsharpi
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 4.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> open System.Windows.Forms;;
> let f = new Form();;
val f : Form = System.Windows.Forms.Form, Text:
```

Comment: When I click on the window that appears after I do f.Show(), all gets stuck and unresponsive. Does this happen to you too?

Comment: @GerardoZinno I did see some odd "spinning beachball" behavior when my cursor was over certain elements, but my form was otherwise responsive.